# How to create an input element in c# mvc which allows only ipv4 and ipv6 address with html validation?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I want to use an input field in MVC to enter an IP address either IPv6 or IPv4. It would be very helpful if it does include the address masking.

I tried using html attribute 'pattern' with value

```
@pattern = @"^(([0-9a-fA-F]{1}|[1-9a-fA-F]{1}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,3}):){7}([0-9a-fA-F]{1}|[1-9a-fA-F]{1}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,3})$"
```

for IPv6

and

```
@pattern = @"^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$"
```

for IPv4

but it does not validate in the html side and just excepts whatever is entered.

Below is the code for editor box

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartIPAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ip-address-v6", @pattern = @"^(([0-9a-fA-F]{1}|[1-9a-fA-F]{1}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,3}):){7}([0-9a-fA-F]{1}|[1-9a-fA-F]{1}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,3})$" } })


@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartIPAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ip-address-v4", @pattern = @"^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$" } })
```

Comment: @Asihs you need Jquery masking check this link https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/IP%20Address/

Comment: @jishansiddique I had already tried with one of the jquery masking plugin called "Simple jQuery IPv4 / IPv6 Addresses Input Mask Plugin"  but that was not properly working while entering the inputs. I tried with that plugin as i want to have both ipv4 and ipv6 masking.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $("#textboxid").blur(function () {

        var input = $(this).val();
        console.log(input);
        var regex = new RegExp('(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.) 
        {3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$');
        if (regex.test(input)) {
            alert ("match");
        } else {
            alert("nomatch");
        }


});
```

Regular Expression above given is only for IPV4 you can also include IPV4 Regular Expression Check. Instead of Alert you can use your changes.